# Generic equality lifting in coq

Tags: coq

Is there any tactic or fact or something else to lift equality into a constructor of inductive and reverse, unlift equality of inductive constructors to equality of constructor arguments, i.e.:

```
forall T: Type, forall t1 t2: T, Some t1 = Some t2 -> t1 = t2 
forall T: Type, forall t1 t2: T, t1 = t2 -> Some t1 = Some t2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first principle is usually known as the injectivity of constructors, and there are multiple tactic that can use it. One option is the `injection` tactic:

```
Goal forall T: Type, forall t1 t2: T, Some t1 = Some t2 -> t1 = t2.
intros T t1 t2 H. injection H as H. apply H.
Qed.
```

The other principle is valid for any function, not just constructors.  You can use the `f_equal` tactic:

```
Goal forall T: Type, forall t1 t2: T, t1 = t2 -> Some t1 = Some t2.
intros T t1 t2 H. f_equal. exact H.
Qed.
```

Note that in this situation it is often easier to simply rewrite with the equality, since it avoids generating multiple goals when you have a multiple-argument function:

```
Goal forall T: Type, forall t1 t2: T, t1 = t2 -> Some t1 = Some t2.
intros T t1 t2 H. rewrite H. trivial.
Qed.
```